# ListFragment обработка нажатий по Item

Tags: java, android, listview, android-fragment, click

Есть обработчик:

```
private int previousPosition = -1;

@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);

    ImageView image;

    if (previousPosition == position) {
        image = v.findViewById(R.id.btnPlay);
        image.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_btn_play);
        previousPosition = -1;
    } else {
        image = v.findViewById(R.id.btnPlay);
        image.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_btn_pause);
        previousPosition = position;
    }

}
```

Сам лист

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<ListView
    android:id="@id/android:list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:listitem="@layout/fragment_item"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:background="@color/bg_listView"
    android:listSelector="@drawable/item_bg"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@id/android:empty"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:text="@string/no_data" />
</LinearLayout>
```

И его элемент

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<TableRow
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/btnPlay"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_btn_play"
        android:background="@null"
        android:contentDescription="@string/contentDescriptionPlay"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="12dp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvSong"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/song"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:textSize="17sp"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvSinger"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/singer"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</TableRow>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvDuration"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="end"
    android:text="@string/duration"
    android:textAlignment="viewEnd"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="17dp"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

Выглядит так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

То есть при клике по элементу изображение меняется на "паузу", при повторном клике на "плей".

**Проблема:** когда выбираешь, например, первый элемент, изображение меняется не только у него, но и у элемента ниже (который не виден на текущем экране - немного скролла вниз и видно)

**UPD:**
Код с адаптером:

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    Handler mHandler = new Handler(hc);
    fileRead = new FileRead(mHandler);
}

Handler.Callback hc = new Handler.Callback() {
    @Override
    public boolean handleMessage(Message msg) {
        switch (msg.what) {
            case MESSAGE_READ:
                playlist = fileRead.getPlaylist();
                ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> myArrList = new ArrayList<>();
                HashMap<String, String> map;

                for (int i = 0; i < playlist.size(); i++){
                    map = new HashMap<>();
                    Track t = playlist.get(i);
                    map.put("song", t.getSong());
                    map.put("singer", t.getSinger());
                    map.put("duration", getDurationOfMin(t.getDuration()));
                    myArrList.add(map);
                }

                SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getActivity(), myArrList,
                        R.layout.fragment_item,
                        new String[] {"song", "singer", "duration"},
                        new int[] {R.id.tvSong, R.id.tvSinger, R.id.tvDuration});
                setListAdapter(adapter);
                break;
        }
        return false;
    }
};
```

Comment: Код адаптера покажите.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решил проблему следующим образом.

Добавил `ImageView` в `HashMap` для адаптера и изменяю `ImageView` в `onListItemClick()`. Изменение происходит путем замены значения в массиве `myArrayList` методом `set()` по позиции от клика. После логических изменений - уведомляю адаптер о изменениях `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`

***Код наполнения адаптера:***

```
Handler.Callback hc = new Handler.Callback(){
@Override
public boolean handleMessage(Message msg) {
        switch (msg.what) {
            case MESSAGE_READ:
                playlist = fileRead.getPlaylist();
                myArrList = new ArrayList<>();

                for (int i = 0; i < playlist.size(); i++){
                    myArrList.add(putMap(playlist.get(i), IMG_PLAY));
                }

                adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getActivity(),
                        myArrList, R.layout.fragment_item, from, to);
                setListAdapter(adapter);
                break;
        }
        return false;
    }
};

private HashMap<String, Object> putMap(Track track, int img) {
    HashMap<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();

    map.put(MAP_KEY_IMG, img);
    map.put(MAP_KEY_SONG, track.getSong());
    map.put(MAP_KEY_SINGER, track.getSinger());
    map.put(MAP_KEY_DURATION, getDurationOfMin(track.getDuration()));

    return map;
}
```

Обработка клика:

```
private int previousPosition = -1;

@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);

    if (previousPosition == position){
        myArrList.set(position,
                putMap(playlist.get(position), IMG_PLAY));
        previousPosition = -1;
    } else {
        if (previousPosition != -1){
            myArrList.set(previousPosition,
                    putMap(playlist.get(previousPosition), IMG_PLAY));
        }
        myArrList.set(position,
                putMap(playlist.get(position), IMG_PAUSE));
        previousPosition = position;
    }
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Таким образом:

- Нажатие на `Item` - изменение `ImageView` на `Pause` (по умолчанию `Play`)
- Повторное нажатие на `Item` - вернуть `Play`
- Нажатие на другой `Item` - `Pause` для нового `Item`, `Play` для предыдущего

[Помог данный урок](http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/110-urok-51-simpleadapter-dobavlenie-i-udalenie-zapisej.html)